# Gradle Spring Boot Dependency Not found Multi Module Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to set up multimodule project

RootProject Settings

```
rootProject.name = 'Abc'

include 'catalog'
include 'catalog-common'
```

Root Project Abc/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

subprojects {

    group = 'com.abc'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }


    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.3"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    }

}
```

Module catalog-common

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Module Catalog

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':catalog-common')
}
```

in Catalog Project it is expecting again to define spring dependencies but where as I am able to access java static classes

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `catalog-common` is a kind of "library" module, consumed by other sub-projects (`catalog` and maybe others). If so, you should use the [Java Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin which can be used for this purpose. You will then need to configure all dependencies you want to "inherit" in consumer projects using `api` configuration instead of `implementation`. Dependencies declared in `implementation` will not leak into consumer projects, this is the expected Gradle behavior.

In you example, `catalog-common` build script should look like:

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
}
dependencies {
    // choose between api or implementation, depending on the scope you want for each dependency
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Please note that it seems a bit strange to configure some of the Spring dependencies like `actuator` in this common library: this should declared only in the main "application" project ( `catalog` in your case), unless you want to implement some common code depending on `actuator` in the `catalog-common` module.